# Trying to develop a Save button where if not clicked before exit is clicked, it will reject all changes to the database table since last save

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to figure out a way to create a save button. The way my project works is the user will create a record into a database table at the click of a button after filling in information using textboxes (done with an insert query) which the user can also go back to make changes to if needed (done with an update query) but if later on the user does not click the 'save' button and continues to exit/close the form then I want all the changes to the database to be rejected since the last save click. Basically I want the insert query to be undone and any update queries to be undone, or if save was clicked after an insert query but not after an update query then undo the update query.

Comment: if your gonna take the time to downvote you could atleast explain why otherwise you're not helping.

Comment: How is what you describe any different than just saving when they click a button (and doing nothing when they dont and just exit)?

Comment: Why don´t you just insert/update the stuff in the database when the user clicks the save button? Much easier than implementing an undo functionality. BindingSources etc. are made for these scenarios.

Comment: @Plutonix because it's technically saved when they insert into the database whether or not they clicked save. So I want to undo the insert if they don't want to save.

Comment: @Nathan, I believe Pluto and Alex are suggesting that you change your solution so that it DOESN'T do any inserts/updates until the user clicks the "Save" button.  Just keep everything in memory until then.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yeah true. just wish I thought of doing that before I did my entire project... fml

Comment: Measure twice, cut once.  A datatable can also be used to rollback changes

Comment: In terms of time: I think implementing an in-memory structure like Datatables or similar will not take more time than creating and maintaining a Memento...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.   Here are a couple:

1) If the user exits the page without clicking save, run DELETE queries to remove the rows that you inserted.

2) While the user is clicking around, insert/update a staging table(s).  When the user clicks "Save" commit the changes to the real table.

Comment: While these will work, what will happen if the program crashes?  Then the DELETE functions or committing the staging table data to the real tables will not happen and then the programmer will have to write code to handle these scenarios.